# What's wrong with the MySQL DATE() function?

Tags: mysql, date

I've had some bizarre results from queries I've been testing out with the `DATE` function, culminating in these little beauties:

```
mysql> SELECT id FROM job WHERE DATE(due)=CURRENT_DATE;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT id FROM job WHERE DATE(due)=CURRENT_DATE AND id>2022;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT id FROM job WHERE DATE(due)=CURRENT_DATE AND id=2023;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
| 2023 | 
+------+
```

and for a bit more comedy

```
mysql> SELECT id, DATE(due) FROM job WHERE DATE(due) IS NULL AND id>2022;
```

gives us:

```
+------+------------+
| id   | DATE(due)  |
+------+------------+
| 2023 | 2009-08-24 | 
| 2024 | 2009-08-24 | 
| 2025 | NULL       | 
| 2026 | 2009-08-24 | 
| 2027 | NULL       | 
| 2032 | NULL       | 
| 2031 | NULL       | 
| 2033 | NULL       | 
| 2034 | NULL       | 
| 2035 | NULL       | 
| 2036 | NULL       | 
| 2037 | NULL       | 
| 2038 | NULL       | 
+------+------------+
```

this is on 5.0.45

Is the `DATE()` function completely unreliable, or am I missing something?

**Clarifications:**

The due field is of type `datetime`, and there hasn't been a date rollover in the intervening period between the queries - all queries mentioned above are still giving the same results and `NOW()` is currently `2009-08-24 22:54:17`

In answer to Eric's query:

```
mysql> SELECT id, due, DATE(due) FROM job WHERE id>2022;
+------+---------------------+------------+
| id   | due                 | DATE(due)  |
+------+---------------------+------------+
| 2023 | 2009-08-24 00:00:00 | 2009-08-24 | 
| 2024 | 2009-08-24 17:20:56 | 2009-08-24 | 
| 2025 | NULL                | NULL       | 
| 2026 | 2009-08-24 17:22:07 | 2009-08-24 | 
| 2027 | NULL                | NULL       | 
| 2032 | NULL                | NULL       | 
| 2031 | NULL                | NULL       | 
| 2033 | NULL                | NULL       | 
| 2034 | NULL                | NULL       | 
| 2035 | NULL                | NULL       | 
| 2036 | NULL                | NULL       | 
| 2037 | NULL                | NULL       | 
| 2038 | NULL                | NULL       | 
+------+---------------------+------------+
```

Comment: A maybe stupid question: if you try it right now, does it give you same results? May it be that date changed between your queries?

Comment: What is the type of column id? is it an auto-increment/serial field of type integer or something else?

Comment: what is the type of field due?

Comment: Can we see `select id, due, date(due) from job where id > 2022`?

Comment: running into all kinds of flaky date-comparison behavior. wtf is wrong with mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `TO_DAYS` function is a whole lot more reliable for my purposes - a straight replacement of `DATE` with `TO_DAYS` seems to be going alright.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
SELECT id FROM (SELECT * FROM job WHERE due IS NOT NULL) job_not_null WHERE DATE(due) = CURRENT_DATE
```

I was able to reproduce the behavior where the comparison failed after the first NULL value in the column.

Comment: Thanks - it also looks like I can have `WHERE due IS NOT NULL AND ...` instead of the subquery, but I'm a bit hesitant to use `DATE` at all now.